# Is there a way to port Apple's Speech Synthesis Library to Linux?

Tags: linux, text-to-speech, speech

I wasn't able to find any TTS library that would suit my needs except for Apple's Speech Synthesis Library.
Is there any way to port the library to Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

That library is a proprietary component of macOS. Apple has never released any of the source code, so there's nothing available to port.